# Problems with using Contact Form 7 in an Elementor Pro Popup

Tags: jquery, wordpress, elementor

I use Contact Form 7 on my WordPress website.

When I use the form shortcode in an Elementor Pro Popup,
popup dissapears after hitting the submit button and the user is unable to see any form messages.

To remedy this problem, I use the following code and it seems to work fine. Popup is still visible displaying form messages after hitting the submit button:

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).on( 'elementor/popup/show', () => {
    wpcf7.init(jQuery(".wpcf7-form")[0]);
});
</script>
```

Because I'm a JS novice, above code throws out 2 syntax errors. How can I please eliminate these errors?

Error 1: On line #1

'arrow function syntax (=>)' is only available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6').

Error 2: On line #2

Strings must use singlequote.

'wpcf7' is not defined.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery does not use ES6 arrow functions and the double-quoted string needs to be single quotes:

```
<script>
  jQuery( document ).on( 'elementor/popup/show', function() {
     wpcf7.initForm( jQuery('.wpcf7-form') );
  });
</script>
```

Comment: what is the intention here? If you are using wpcf7, that should be defined. But I don't know the purpose of this code, what i's meant to acheive

Comment: Well, I don't know if it will make a difference, but I updated my answer. Can you give that a try?

Answer (score 0):

Please note:

If you use the same form on the page AND in Elementor Popup, the above code will need tweeking:

You must use a different form for the in page and the popup.
And you must add an extra class to the popup form shortcode:

E.g.  [contact-form-7 id="3296" title="Form Popup" html_class="popup-form"]

so the script above will be:

```
<script>
  jQuery( document ).on( 'elementor/popup/show', function() {
     wpcf7.init(jQuery('.popup-form')[0]);
  });
</script>
```